# Get the value of a column that is using a ButtonField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` and one of the columns has a `TemplateField` using a `LinkButton` (`ButtonField`)
I can get the value of a specific cell in my Grid Just fine. Using:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

I then display the text from that cell in a `Label`.

However I cannot get this to work with a `ButtonField` Template. It only works with a non Template column.

How can I get the value of a specific cell in a column that is using a `ButtonField` / `TemplateField`?

EDIT: This is My Button Field Code inside my GridView:
`<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select" />`

Also, this is happening in this event:

```
protected void gvManagerCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Could you provide your GridView aspx code?

Comment: With 26 questions on the site, you should know how to format the code in your posts.  (*And, less obviously, to not put signatures at the end.*)

Comment: I'm not sure how to format my code yet. Not familiar with Markup. And what do you care if I leave my name at the end of whatever??

Comment: if you provide the markup you are using for your ButtonField / TemplateField it would give a lot better idea of any potential solutions.  Also when are you trying to retrieve the text from that cell - button_click? page_load etc.

Comment: @dice. Thanks. Please see above edited post with Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are issues with hyperlinkfield and buttonfield but there is a work around.  Say you are binding buttonfield text based on a column called ButtonNames, and in that column you have all your names, such as "button bob", "button jerry" etc.  In your GridView, add an invisible column as your very first column and bind its value as ButtonNames. You make it invisible by setting one of the visibility properties. Forgot what it was from top of my head.  Then, when you want to get the text for the buttonfield simply get the data from that invisible column instead  Same applies to hyperlinkfiends.

EDIT: here's some code.

```
<asp:BoundColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="ButtonNames" SortExpression="ButtonNames" HeaderText="TriageId" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

Then you retrieve it via string s = e.Item.Cells[0].Text where e is a DataGridCommandEventArgs or something to that nature.

Comment: This doesn't work. I had to use Leon's suggestion. That one got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

See if `var Button = row.Cells["Customer"].Controls[0];` would retrieve the button you need.

You might need to cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a controls collection in the cell - you may be able to access it there.

Though a simpler way would be to use something like:

```
Label l = row.FindControl("myControlId");
```

**EDIT:** true the exact approach above does not work - but you can use the controls, the following does work, note that what we are doing here is pretty much rife with bad practices (but then we are using a GridView for convenience sake after all).

```
protected void gvManagerCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = ((sender as GridView).SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton).Text;
}
```

In order to figure this out set up a debug environment and breakpoint in the handler method then drill down through the class hierarchy.  The debugger is our friend ;)

**EDIT** just to mention the obvious - the column is hard coded here - you will probably have to change it.

Comment: I tried this approach. However for some reason giving a Control in a Datagridview an ID is not allowed or supported.